# PCIe 2.0 or PCIe 2.1?

Tags: dvi, pci-express

I'm looking around for a Graphics card, and I found this one:

http://products.amd.com/en-us/GraphicCardDetail.aspx?id=290&f1=PC&f2=AMD+Radeon%E2%84%A2+HD+6000+Series+&f3=&f4=&f5=&f6=PCIe+x16+Gen+2.0&f7=&f8=Yes&f9=Yes&f10=&f11=&f12=Yes&f13=0&f14=0&f15=0&f16=0&f17=0&f18=2&f19=1&f20=0&f21=0&

It says here the card is for a PCIe x16 2.0.

I went to found the card on NewEgg, and it says the card is PCIe x16 2.1.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814121418

My computer's bus is a PCIe x16 2.0, and I wasn't sure if the card would work, do you guys know what kind of bus this card is actually for?

Secondly, I'll explain I'm trying to get three DVI monitors working, and I'm hoping this card will do it -- I take it I'll be able to use the two DVIs and then use an adapter to get one of the HDMI slots working with DVI?

And finally, you don't have any other recommendations for cards that would work better for 3 monitors? I'm looking to stay under the ~$225 area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All version of PCI-Express are compatible. Compliance with all earlier PCI-Express revisions is a compliance requirement for all currently deployed version of PCI-Express. *Every* PCI-Express 2.1 device or slot is also a PCI-Express 2.0 device or slot.

Comment: So a 2.0 card in a 2.1 slot is fine, but how about the reverse, a 2.1 card in a 2.0 slot?

Comment: @Hand, he already said that would be okay (of course, backwards-compatibility only means that it works, not that it works at full-speed/power/functionality, etc.) When you use a device in an older, but compatible system, (eg slow RAM in a fast system or fast RAM in a slow system), it will work but will be limited to the slower/older/etc. of the two.

Comment: A 2.1 card *is* a 2.0 card. Complying with the PCI-Express 2.0 specification is a requirement for being able to claim to be a PCI-Express 2.1 device. (If it's not a PCI-Express 2.0 device, it *cannot* *be* a PCI-Express 2.1 device -- just as if it's not a car, it cannot be a green car.)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the phrase "device or slot".  Thanks for clarifying!